# fundamentals of networking and digital communication

Tags: networking

Suppose that a group of computers is connected to an Ethernet LAN. If the computers communicate only with each other, does it make sense to use IP protocol in the computers? Should the computers run TCP directly over Ethernet? How is addressing handled?

Comment: What addressing? Have a look at at the OSI model.

Comment: Sure, you still use IP and ARP, unless your application have specific valid reason not to. (Actually, I'm not sure if "to run TCP directly over Ethernet" is even a thing.)

Answer (score 1):

> If the computers communicate only with each other, does it make sense to use IP protocol in the computers?

So much software assumes the ubiquity of IP, but if you are not using any such software, there's no need for IP.  You could not have any devices that expect anything but Ethernet frames between you and the computers.  You may run into problems with firewalls, managed switches, etc.

> Should the computers run TCP directly over Ethernet?

You can't run standards-based TCP without IP, as TCP utilizes IP addresses.  You would have to use your own custom streaming protocol that's based on Ethernet or other link layer as a lower layer.

One thing IP does is abstract the link layer from upper levels of the stack - there was a time where it was possible you could have Ethernet or token ring, and there are things like PPP and HDLC, and also the loopback interface.

If you want to experiment with something similar without developing your own protocols, you could try to run IPX/SPX or AppleTalk over a small network.

> How is addressing handled?

This is something you get to decide when you create your custom protocol above.  An option if you don't want to support routing at all is just using the MAC address.  Non-IP protocols like IPX/SPX and AppleTalk had their own address schemes and methods to obtain host addresses.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple questions here.

The first talks about using IP in a man. Yes, this is a good idea because the protocol is ubiquitous. In the distant past before the internet was a thing there were mtiple competing protocols, but for the general case that's fallen by the way as IP is well understood, standardised, easy to code for and extensible

TCP sits on top of IP, rather then replacing it - you require IPs ability to recognise and route packets. TCP adds a layer on top of this to provide reliable sessions.

With respect of IP addressing there are options. Using a DHCP server centralised control, but using static IPs can be easier to configure. You don't need a router for either method. As I understand it If you use IPv6 you don't need to specify an IP address at all as it can autoconfig a working IP address based on your MAC address.

Answer (score -1):

As you describe, the PCs wouldn't have access to the internet. If this is true, you wouldn't have access to a DHCP server. You would then need to create your own subnet and configure your own IP address's on your own PCs, and since you arent communicating with a server, TCP should be irrelevant.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can run DHCP without a router. More importantly, many (most?) applications - including Windows File Sharing - will use TCP - which sits on top of IP.